# How to fix error[E0283] in RUST while installing cargo-generate?

Tags: rust

I was trying to run this cargo install command

```
cargo install cargo-generate --features vendored-openssl
```

and got this error

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed in RUST while installing cargo-generate
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with updated dependencies. The issue ist tracked [here](https://github.com/cargo-generate/cargo-generate/issues/276).

You can work around this issue by using the dependencies as they are specified the `Cargo.lock` file of the current `cargo-generate` crate version. To do so use this command:

`cargo install --locked cargo-generate --features vendored-openssl`